# React Native IOS: Build Configuration for Release Has Lots of Warnings

Tags: ios, react-native

I'm trying to release a React Native app and I'm a little nervous because I'm getting several hundred warnings while building. I'll start from the begining:

In "Build target React" I'm getting several of the following warnings:

- `"Unused parameter" warning`
- `"code will never be executed" warning`

Then under "Build target [app name]" > "Generate [app name].app.dSYM" I'm getting hundreds of the following warnings:

- `/ModuleCache/ "No such file or directory" warnings`
- `"Could not resolve external type c:objc(cs)[...]" warnings`

In total it is over 200 warnings.

Any thoughts would be appreciated.